# how to display data like "name" and "email" after the user logged in and signed up

Tags: php, mysql

I'm relatively new to coding. I'm trying to display some of the data the user has saved (when registering) on the next few pages. I can display the username, but I want to display the names and email as well.

this is when the user is logging in.

```
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users 
                WHERE username='$username' 
                AND password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
        header('location: indexclient.php');
    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
    }

    //new page
    //This is the top of the page where I want to display the name.

    session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "You must log in first";
        header('location: loginclient.php');
    }

    if (isset($_GET['logout'])) {
        session_destroy();
        unset($_SESSION['username']);
        header("location: loginclient.php");
    }

    //This is where I want to display the name at the bottom of the page:

  <h2> <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>'s Profile</h2>
  <?php echo $_SESSION['firstname']; ?>

  <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
   echo "Hello",  $_SESSION['firstname']  ;
  }
```

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: You need to fetch details through DB Table.

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Some sensible code indentation would be a good idea. It helps us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: ___but I want to display the names and email as well___ Well in that case you will have to either place those items in the SESSION along with `$_SESSION['username']` OR Go and read them from the database on each page using `$_SESSION['username']` as the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fetch data from DB and store in variables so you can use them wherever you want.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
  $name = $data['name_from_db']; //Here you put a name of column where you store name in DB
  $email = $data['email_from_db']; //Here you put a name of column where you store email in DB

 // You can put in session if you want to have it globaly
}

if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
    $_SESSION['name'] = $name ; //This is example where I put in SESSION variable
    $_SESSION['email'] = $email; //This is example where I put in SESSION variable
    header('location: indexclient.php');
} else {
    array_push($errors, "Wrong username/password combination");
}
```

Please note, you are not doing anything for security in this code and it's wide open for attacks. Please, read about [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712037/what-is-parameterized-query) and protection against SQL injection, also about password hashing. Sending passwords in plain text is not safe!

Answer (score 0):

On this section :

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    //Add another entry in SESSION here
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
    header('location: indexclient.php');
}
```

You can add a new entry like `$_SESSION['email'] = $result[index_of_email_in_results]`